# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (60)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have problem with mac m1, when i connect via ip address error like this

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (60),

and if connect to external ip address same problem with mac m1, if connect with localhost, it's no problem.

im using xampp 8.2.0-0. firewall has disable, can someone help me, i not have solution with this trouble.

Thank You very much.

connect via LAN same problem, to local with ip address 127.0.0.1 same problem, only can connect if using localhost, ex.

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin ./mysql -h localhost -u root
```

like this no problem.

Comment: MySQL user accounts have what is called a Domain from which they are allowed to connect. `127.0.0.1` is a domain and `localhost` is a domain. If your user account is only setup with the `locahost` domain, you wont be allowed to connect using `127.0.0.1`

Comment: PS: I think XAMPP now only uses `mariaDB`

Comment: @RiggsFolly — If that was the issue wouldn't it be an "invalid credentials" error not a "cannot connect" error?

Comment: There *must* be a dozen duplicates around somewhere, but I'm pretty sure this will be caused by MySQL being configured to listen on a local UNIX Socket and not on TCP/IP.

Comment: @Quentin Good point, must find my glasses

Comment: Connect via localhost and run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking';` to check whether `skip_networking` is turned on. If it is, follow instructions in question linked by Quentin.